# Matplotlib is not finishing the process so I have to end it manually

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, spyder

I´m using matplotlib in spyder. It was working fine until I updated the Windows. Currently I have Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8.1 for Windows 11, version 22H2 for x64 (KB5034467). Could this be the cause?

since this problem appear, it takes too much time to the plot to display, and when it is shown it doesn´t finish the proccess. When I press stop I get this messages:

```
File ~\Documents\AU\CPrediction\visualization.py:114 in plot_treadmillData
    plt.show()

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:446 in show
    return _get_backend_mod().show(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:3620 in show
    cls.mainloop()

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py:604 in start_main_loop
    with _maybe_allow_interrupt(qapp):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\contextlib.py:144 in __exit__
    next(self.gen)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py:245 in _maybe_allow_interrupt
    old_sigint_handler(*handler_args)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

I have searched online and I couldn´t find anything. Could the new version of Windows be the problem? I already tried with restarting the kernel, closing spyder, closing anaconda and restart the computer and nothing changed.
Thanks!